# Lambert's O(n^2) algorithm on pairwise sum sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Sorting Pairwise Sums of X and Y with **O(n^2)** comparisons are quite hard.

http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P41.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_%2B_Y_sorting

It seems *Lambert* has concluded that if some non-comparison operations are allowed, then it is achievable.

I can find his original paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759290089X

Also I found a [functional approach](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZQJnYoAmw6gC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=Lambert%20algorithm%20Pairwise%20Sums&source=bl&ots=7A8zvCOtzG&sig=KxUV2oP6MKttANp-tdgmetcSw7s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JC-5VJL6OsGyUcWwg8gH&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Lambert%20algorithm%20Pairwise%20Sums&f=false) for his algorithm.

---

However, I really don't understand even after several times of attempts.

So what I roughly know is his algorithm tries:

1. tag element with its original index
2. negate it
3. using the equation of `X - Y < X' - Y' == X - X' < Y - Y'`.

Other than that I am totally lost.

---

So anyone here really understands that algorithm? Can anyone clearly explain it in a simple way?